# WP8 - How to disable the app Splash Screen for certain pages?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013

I have an app that uses a Splash Screen when it opens up, and it works fine.
The problem is that I've added a couple of pages that can be accessed via two live tiles, and the point is to let the user istantly load a certain section of the app without having to load the whole MainPage.xaml page, which is quite heavy to load.

These two pages are really simple and load almost istantly, but the app loads the Splash Screen anyways, and I don't like that.

Is there a way to "disable" the splash screen for a specific page?
Via C# or directly from the XAML, I don't know.
I enabled the Splash Screens simply by adding the SplashScreenImage.screen-WXGA.jpg (720p and 1080p as well) to the project main directory.

Thanks! :)
Sergio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can't disable the splash screen. What you can do is to minimize all initialization work your app has to do so that the splash screen is shown for a minimum of time.

Comment: Am I doing it right if I create the whole UI in C# and put the code inside a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() in the page constructor?
This way the UI should be loaded asynchronously after the page loaded up, right?

Answer (score 1):

Sergio,
You can simulate a splash screen and decide based on how you were activated to show it or not.  This sample shows one way to do it: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Splash-screen-sample-89c1dc78/

I would show it for the main xaml and others that take a long time to load and dismiss it in code.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)
I saw the project you linked, but my app is for WP8.0, so I can't use that method. I think I'll keep the actual splash screen and try to load some content in background to let the page load up as fast as possibile. I'll keep that project in mind when I'll manage to port my app to WP8.1 though :D